# How to check whether the entered symbol is char or not?

Tags: c

I have a problem with calculator. I want to program a calculator, but it "works" with letters too. If I enter f.e letters "s" and "u", i get answer 0. How to repair that?

```
# include <stdio.h>

int main() {

char operator;
int a,b;

printf("Enter the operator (+, -, *, /): ");
scanf("%c", &operator);

printf("Enter two number and seperate them with space: ");
scanf("%lf %lf",&a, &b);

switch(operator)
{
    case '+':
        printf("%.2lf + %.2lf = %.2lf",a, b, a + b);
        break;

    case '-':
        printf("% 2lf - %.2lf = % 2lf",a, b, a - b);
        break;

    case '*':
        printf("%.2lf * %.2lf = %.2lf",a, b, a * b);
        break;

    case '/':
        printf("%.2lf / %.2lf = %.2lf",a, b, a / b);
        break;


    default:
        printf("Error!");

}

return 0;
}
```

Sorry, if the question has been up here.
The link to answer is also appreciated!
Cheers!

Comment: Please check the return value from `scanf` which in this case must be `1` and `2` respectively in the first and second call.

Comment: If you skip the `scanf` part and just use [`getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) you can read in one character at a time and parse this in a more generic way.

Comment: What is it supposed to do with letters?

Comment: @EugeneSh. If I use letters, it gives answer f.e: "0.00 + 0.00 = 0.00"

Comment: Note that `scanf("%lf %lf",&s, &b);` is expecting pointers to `double s, b;` variables but you defined `int a, b;` Is this the exact code?

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought you want it to work with letters somehow as well.

Comment: Is `&s` a typo? I assume you meant `&a`. But `a` and `b` are type `int` and the `%lf` in the `scanf` call expects `a` and `b` to be type `double`.

Comment: After the edit, you still have the wrong variable type, or format specifier (or both??) Don't you get a compiler warning?

Comment: @IanAbbott Thanks, it was a typo.

Comment: If `scanf` does not return 2 for the second case (two `double`s), you should report an error as that means the input to the program is invalid. Similarly for the first case (one `char`), you should check that `scanf` returned 1.

Comment: @WeatherVane I dont get a compiler warning. What should be the correct variable type?

Comment: You should be using `double a, b;` Does your compiler have a warning level setting?

Comment: @WeatherVane I use Dev-C++, i think there isnt a warning level setting.

Comment: Have you tried the option `-Wall`? Or "Tools - Compiler Options - Settings - Warnings".

Comment: @EugeneSh. If it is possible, I would like that if one of the a or b is letter, then the answer would be just a and b written together with operator. F.e: 2/s or s*9 or s+s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made the corrections discussed in comments

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {                                            // correct definition

    char operator;
    double a,b;                                             // correct type

    printf("Enter the operator (+, -, *, /): ");
    if(scanf("%c", &operator) != 1) {                       // add error check
        puts("Bad operator entered");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Enter two number and seperate them with space: ");
    if(scanf("%lf %lf",&a, &b) != 2) {                      // add error check
        puts("Bad value(s) entered");
        return 1;
    }

    switch(operator)
    {
        case '+':
            printf("%.2lf + %.2lf = %.2lf",a, b, a + b);
            break;

        case '-':
            printf("%.2lf - %.2lf = % 2lf",a, b, a - b);    // corrected typo
            break;

        case '*':
            printf("%.2lf * %.2lf = %.2lf",a, b, a * b);
            break;

        case '/':
            printf("%.2lf / %.2lf = %.2lf",a, b, a / b);
            break;

        default:
            printf("Error!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As you know dividing by 0 cant be done. So how to make the program to give error when dividing by 0?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED:**

i found my Ooldest code in library Folder maybe it helps you in that problem. This will definitely Work.

```
char operator;
printf("Enter the Operation in ( * , / , - , + )");
scanf("%s",&operator);
if(operator!='+' || operator!='-' || operator!='*' || operator!='/')
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That won't trap `EOF`. You should explicitly check the number of items to be scanned: `if(scanf("%c", &operator) != 1)` In the case of the two floating point operands, you must check for `2` because the first might have a valid entry, but the second might not, in which case `fscanf` will return `1` instead of `2` which your check won't catch.

Comment: If I put the line you added, my code jumps straight to default and prints "Error" even if i put correct operator and numbers.

Comment: Whose line? Sayed's or mine?

Comment: @WeatherVane Both. Where I should put the line: right after first scanf or later?

Comment: That does not make sense: it *is* the `scanf` line.

Comment: @WeatherVane Can You somehow give the correct code, please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190323/discussion-between-martin-suits-and-weather-vane).

Comment: Sorry for the bad code. maybe you should check the updated code now.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. It was easier to do than I thought.
So the right code, I'll put comment to answer.
    #include

```
int main(void) {                                            // correct definition

char operator;
double a,b;                                             // correct type

printf("Enter the operator (+, -, *, /): ");
if(scanf("%c", &operator) != 1) {                       // add error check
    puts("Bad operator entered");
    return 1;
}

printf("Enter two number and seperate them with space: ");
if(scanf("%lf %lf",&a, &b) != 2) {                      // add error check
    puts("Bad value(s) entered");
    return 1;
}

switch(operator)
{
    case '+':
        printf("%.2lf + %.2lf = %.2lf",a, b, a + b);
        break;

    case '-':
        printf("%.2lf - %.2lf = % 2lf",a, b, a - b);    // corrected typo
        break;

    case '*':
        printf("%.2lf * %.2lf = %.2lf",a, b, a * b);
        break;

    case '/':
        if(b!=0){                                    //added an if-sentence
            printf("%.2lf / %.2lf = %.2lf\n",a, b, 
            a / b);
        }
        else
            printf("Can't divide by zero\n");
        break;


    default:
        printf("Error!");
}
return 0;
}
```

Basically, I just put an if-sentence to case('/').